# git on my vps with CentOS 7.0 Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. each time

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos7

When I login to my server and execute `git pull`
I get:

```
no such identity: /home/admin/.ssh/gitHubKey: No such file or directory
no such identity: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have to execute this 2 command:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and it working until I logged out and login again .

NOTE: I have generate the `ssh-rsa` and saved it to as new ssh key.

Comment: How des you configuration file `~/.ssh/config` look like?

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = git@github.com:***/***.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
[credential]
 helper = store

Comment: no, that is `.git/config`. I asked for `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitHubKey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer

Comment: Remove that and add there only `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` if that is not shared account. It should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitHubKey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer
```

from `~/.ssh/config` and add there only

```
`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
```

if that is not shared account and somebody else could make a use of the other options.

It should do the job.